# how to trim a string in java the right way and split it to 3 separate textviews

Tags: java, android, string, trim

how to trim a string "**120 ### 16 ### 16 ###**" in java and cut out only numbers without spaces to put them in 3 separate text views? string is coming from arduino via bluetooth from distance sensors.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to get all the different numbers:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("120 ### 16 ### 16 ###");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

This ouputs:

```
120
16
16
```

You can check it [here](http://tpcg.io/hm879X6y).

Answer (score 0):

Check if below code serves your purpose.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "120 ### 16 ### 16 ###";

        // removing # from the string
        s = s.replace("#", "");

        //splitting the string with white spaces in an array
        String[] arr = s.split(" ");

        //printing an array
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```